# Passing JVM args to SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, jvm-arguments

My SBT build is echoing:

```
[error] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[error] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

How can I pass the `-Xlint:unchecked` argument to the javac process invoked by SBT?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/BuildConfiguration#Compile_Options

```
override def compileOptions = super.compileOptions ++ 
  compileOptions("-Xlint:unchecked")
```

Comment: Thank you. That would work, but my assumption that it was scalac was incorrect. Javac is presenting the error messages. That same page gave me the right answer... `override def javaCompileOptions = super.javaCompileOptions ++ javaCompileOptions("-Xlint:unchecked")`